# $G/K = \mathbb{Z}_2^m \implies G \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2^{m+1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let's suppose $G$ is a finite group and $G/\mathbb{Z}_2 = \mathbb{Z}_2^m$. Can I deduce from this $G \simeq \mathbb{Z}_2^{m+1}$? Orders of the groups in question are the same.

I'm thinking of an isomorphism like the following: if we had $[a] \mapsto b, b \in \mathbb{Z}_2^m$ then $a \mapsto (b, 0)$ and $ a+1 \mapsto (b,1)$

May be some more geometric or intuitive ideas why this can be true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: take $G = \mathbb Z_4 \oplus \mathbb Z_2^{m-1}$, and the $ \mathbb Z_2 $ you are quotienting is the only nontrivial subgroup of  $\mathbb Z_4$

However,  $G = \mathbb Z_4 \oplus \mathbb Z_2^{m-1}$  and   $G = \mathbb Z_2^{m+1}$ are the only possibilities.